# How to validate radio and array before submitting form?

Tags: javascript, validation, forms

I need to validate two things on this form:
1. There are two radio buttons:
    • OPTION 1 - On click function hides mm/dd/yyyy fields for OPTION 2
    • OPTION 2 - On click function shows mm/dd/yyyy fields which aren't required.
2. Zip code field - Need to validate an array of acceptable zip codes.

I've got this form MOSTLY working aside from a few issues:
1. If you click submit without checking or filling out anything it replaces some of the text on the page with the word "Invalid" and vice versa when valid info has been filled in.
2. It does not go to the next page if valid info has been submitted.
3. It only validates the zipcode field and does not require the radio buttons.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Test page here: http://circleatseven.com/testing/jquery/zipcodevalidation/

Answer (score 0):

If i have you understand you search for this:

I dont have write a Message with "invalid", i give an alert.

In your HTML add "onsubmit" to your form-Tag:

```
<form method="post" action="success.php" id="step1" onsubmit="checkdata();">
```

and add a submit-Button to your form or trigger on your pseudo-submit-button `.submit()` with jQuery.

In your Javascript you add following function:

```
function checkdata() {
            if ($(":radio:checked").length < 1) {
                alert('Please choose an Option!');
                return false;
            }
            zipCodeOk = false;
            zipCodes = new Array(75001, 75002, 75006); //Your Zip-Codes
            for (var i = 0; i <= zipCodes.length; i++) {
                if ($('#enterZip').val() == zipCodes[i]) { 
                    zipCodeOk = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!zipCodeOk) {alert('Please enter a valid Zip-Code!');return false;}
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A friend helped me out.. We ended up using the Jquery validate plugin - here's what we came up with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery.validator.addMethod("validZip", function(value) {
            var zips=['12345', '23456', '34567', '45678', '56789', '67890', '78901', '89012', '90123', '01234'];
            if ($.inArray(value,zips) > -1) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        }, "invalid zip");

        $("#step1").validate({
            rules: {
                currentServiceStatus: "required",
                enterZip: { validZip : true }
            }
        });

        $('.moveInDates').hide();
        $(":radio:eq(0)").click(function(){
            $('.moveInDates').hide();
        });
        $(":radio:eq(1)").click(function(){
            $('.moveInDates').show();
        });

    });
</script>
```

And here's the html:

```
<form method="post" action="success.php" id="step1">

<h1>CHOOSE *</h1>
<input name="currentServiceStatus" type="radio" value="Switch Me" /> OPTION 1
<br/>
<input name="currentServiceStatus" type="radio" value="Move-In" /> OPTION 2 (reveals more fields on click)

<div id="dateInputs" class="moveInDates">
    <h2>Move-In Date (not required)</h2>
    <p><span class="mmddyyyy"><input name="moveInDateMonth" type="text" class="text" id="moveInDateMonth" /> / <input name="moveInDateDay" type="text" class="text" id="moveInDateDay" /> / <input name="moveInDateYear" type="text" class="text" id="moveInDateYear" /></span>
</div>

<hr/>

<h1>ZIP CODE *</h1>
<p>Enter one of the following acceptable Zip Codes:</p>
<p>12345, 23456, 34567, 45678, 56789, 67890, 78901, 89012, 90123, 01234</p>

<input name="enterZip" type="text" class="text" id="enterZip" />

<hr/>

<input type="image" id="submitButton" src="http://circleatseven.com/testing/jquery/zipcodevalidation/library/images/btn_submit.jpg" />
<p><em>* Required</em></p>

</ul>
```